# How to get the invoked JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I am traversing all the components of my Java GUI application starting from the main window. However, the JPopupMenu is only a descendant of the main window if the main window is maximized.

How can I get the instance of a JPopupMenu that is popped outside of the main window? Of course, during the traversal, I eventually have an instance of the invoker. Is there a method that gets the instance of the component that was invoked by invoker? If not, is there any other way to get the instance of the JPopupMenu that is present?

Comment: *"I am traversing all the components of my Java GUI application starting from the main window."*  Why?  See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am not developing the main application, but instead running a custom script on it. My code launches the program in the same JVM, and does some custom analytics on all the GUI components.